# jQuery slideToggle - Loading Twice (Open - Then Close)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've built a site with a Mobile Navigation,

I'm using jQuery to do a slideToggle, But I have a few checks in place, To see if the user has opened the search bar / notifications bar, Then showing hiding so that you only see one of the items at a given time.

My jQuery code is as follows (I'll also provide a Fiddle)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Mobile Nav Toggle...
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function()
    {
        // // Check If Other Items Are Open....
        if($('.mobile-search-form:visible'))
        {
            $('.mobile-search-form').hide();
        }
        // // Check If Other Items Are Open....
        if($('.mobile-notifications:visible'))
        {
            $('.mobile-notifications').hide();
        }

        $('nav').slideToggle();

        accordion_links();

        return false;
    })

    // Add a Chevron Class To Links (For Mobile Nav)...
    $(function() {
        $('nav ul li a').each(function()
        {
            if ( $(this).parent('li').children('ul').size() > 0 )
            {
                $(this).addClass('chevron-down');
            }
        });
    });

    function accordion_links()
    {
        $('.chevron-down').click(function()
        {
            $(this).next('ul.sub-nav').slideToggle();

            if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('open'))
            {
                $(this).removeClass('chevron-up');
                $(this).addClass('chevron-down');
                $(this).parent('li').removeClass('open');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass('chevron-down');
                $(this).addClass('chevron-up');
                $(this).parent('li').addClass('open');
            }
        })
    }

    // Toggle Search Form (On Mobile)....
    $('.search-link').click(function()
    {

        // Check If Notifications / Search Form Are Visible...
         if($('nav:visible'))
         {
                $('nav').slideUp();
         }

         if($('.mobile-notifications:visible'))
         {
            $('.mobile-notifications').hide();
         }

        $('.mobile-search-form').slideToggle();

        return false;
    })

    // Toggle Notifications On Mobile...
    $('a.notifications').click(function()
    {
        // Check If Notifications / Search Form Are Visible...
         if($('nav:visible'))
         {
            $('nav').hide();
         }

         if($('.mobile-search-form:visible'))
         {
            $('.mobile-search-form').hide();
         }

        $('.mobile-notifications').slideToggle();

        return false;
    })

    // Close Notification Block
    $('.close-notification').click(function()
    {
        $('.notification').fadeOut();
    })


})
```

The problem I have, Is the toggle works first time around, But when you click say the search-link, Then load the nav in. The slideToggle tries to do the animation twice (Open then Close)

A jsFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hc8cad7c/)

Why would it be doing this? I can only assume my logic is wrong on this.

Comment: `$('.mobile-search-form:visible')` will always be truthy, You need to check `$('.mobile-search-form:visible').length` property

Comment: Or $('.mobile-search-form').is(':visible') or $('.mobile-search-form').css('display') == 'block' :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Still unfortunately doing the same thing. The toggle seems to fire twice after you've going down the route of closing search. Then re opening the nav

Comment: can you explain better where i should click? i click the search, then the nav, then the search and all seems good... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, jQuery actions run twice if they get called many times. That happens because there are some pending actions in the execution queue which disturb the actions flow.

So I suggest using clearQueue() method in the beginning of your click method, that will guarantee clearing any uncompleted actions before starting the execution of your logic.

Here's the documentation of clearQueue() method https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Answer (score 3):

I modified line 39 of the JS with the `.stop()` and it works (I believe this is the behavior you want):

```
$(this).next('ul.sub-nav').stop().slideToggle();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hc8cad7c/1/

Ok, Here is the second attempt with removing the `slideToggle()` and using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` functions in place of and it appears working at first glance but I do not think it is fully worked out after a couple clicks...

Here are the lines I changed:

```
function accordion_links()
{
    $('.chevron-down').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).parent('li').hasClass('open'))
        {
            $(this).removeClass('chevron-up');
            $(this).addClass('chevron-down');
            $(this).parent('li').removeClass('open');
    $(this).next('ul.sub-nav').slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('chevron-down');
            $(this).addClass('chevron-up');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('open');
    $(this).next('ul.sub-nav').slideDown();
        }
    })
}
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc8cad7c/2/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. The problem I seem to have is when you click the search link, Then re-toggle the Nav. The sub-nav doesn't seem to slideToggle correctly :/

Answer (score 3):

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you! This has solved all my issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try your slideToggle in else condition, because you only have if conditions without else and it always tries to do the animation.

And optionally, comment return false;, I had problems with this line, because sometimes toggle doesn't Works.

Comment: I recently had this issue as posted and your solution to use `return false;` worked for me instantly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update Delegated function change it:

```
$('.chevron-down').click(function()
```

for this:

```
$(document).on("click",'.chevron-down', function()
```

Work better on ajax.